# Laravel 8.54.0 + Livewire : Error SQLSTATE[IMSSP] Tried to bind parameter number 2101. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I use Laravel Framework 8.54.0 and livewire.
I want to call data for my dropdown form. But I get sqlstate error. Could anyone help me find a way to solve this issue?

Model:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'item';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idx';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public const CREATED_AT = 'd_in';
    public const UPDATED_AT = 'd_edit';
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
}
```

Livewire Controller:

```
$this->produk_ictn_row = Item::get();
```

View:

```
<select disabled name="formkodeproduk" id="formkodeproduk" class="form-control @error('formkodeproduk') is-invalid @enderror" wire:model="produk_code">
@foreach($produk_ictn_row as $produk_ictn_row)
    <option value="{{$produk_ictn_row->Kode}}">{{$produk_ictn_row->Kode}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it says you have more than 2100 records so the query should contain all of them in where query!!

Well in some sql serves like microsoft-sql the limit in sql parameter is 2100 , so you have 2 options:

first you can split your query to prevent this error...
second you can split your table and do some parallel queries.

Comment: could you give me link to do some parallel queries in laravel-8?

Comment: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-param-limit-fix

Comment: this is a very simple package to handle the errors and make queries to go block by block